# Flex: How to pass these parameters to my PHP remote service?

Tags: php, apache-flex

Consider the following query which works in MySql:

```
SELECT r.restaurantId, name, city FROM restaurant AS r,
restaurant_restaurant_category AS c
WHERE r.restaurantId = c.restaurantId AND categoryId IN (6, 10)
GROUP BY restaurantId, name, city, phone ORDER BY name
```

This is the method on the remote service (PHP) I am trying to call:

```
public function getRestaurantsByCategories($categories) {
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection,
"SELECT r.restaurantId, name, city FROM restaurant AS r,
restaurant_restaurant_category AS c
WHERE r.restaurantId=c.restaurantId AND categoryId IN (?)
GROUP BY restaurantId, name, city, phone ORDER BY name");
// some other stuff here
}
```

I've have successfully connected to this remote service from the Flex Data services. What I cannot figure out is how to execute the above query from within Flex. E.g. I've tried

```
var array1:Array = new Array();
array1[0] = 6;
array1[1] = 10;
```

and I've tried

```
var string1:String = new String("6,10");
```

calling the remote function like so

```
remoteService.getRestaurantsByCategories(array1);
```

or so

```
remoteService.getRestaurantsByCategories(string1);
```

and so

```
remoteService.getRestaurantsByCategories(array1.join(","));
```

but all of these only return matches for `categoryId=6`.

What's the right way to pass the parameters to PHP so that the query gets executed for both `categoryIds`?

Thanks for any help, folks.

Comment: But do you get a sql error or a flex=php communication error ? can you be more precise and tell what exactly does not work ?

Answer (score 0):

You're not using any kind of remoting framework like AMFPHP or ZendAMF.  It's impossible to call a PHP function from the outside since it's out of scope.  When a PHP script runs, it runs whatever is in the outside of the functions which could then call the functions themselves.

Still, I recommend you use [AMFPHP](http://amfphp.sourceforge.net/) or [ZendPHP](http://framework.zend.com/download/amf) to do this part.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

1. try to set in flex/as3 
   var string1:String = new String(" 6 , 10 "); 
   instead of just "6,10". 
   It may be possible that your string is converted to other type... 
   like int("6,10") ~= 6.
2. Have you tried to force a cast to string on $categories ?
3. Have you put a trace/echo on the $categories value in php? do you get 6,10 ?
4. Can you try to replace the query with:

   ```
   public function getRestaurantsByCategories($categories) 
   {
       $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection,
          "SELECT r.restaurantId, name, city FROM restaurant AS r,
          restaurant_restaurant_category AS c
          WHERE r.restaurantId=c.restaurantId AND categoryId IN ($categosies)
          GROUP BY restaurantId, name, city, phone ORDER BY name");
       // some other stuff here
   }
   ```